# javascript prompt works only refreshing the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, prompt

I wrote a prompt to be able to copy the info into the clipboard to be able to paste it in another window. The function works find, it sends the text I want the user to copy, but only works when I click it the first time. The second time I click it does not do anything until I reload the page, then it works again but only once.

Javascript after closing the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function copyToClipboard(text) {
var info=prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
</script>
```

This is activated in a cell of a table using php and html

```
echo '<td  class="fechasel" onclick="onclick=copyToClipboard(\'test\')"><b>'.$day_num.'';
echo '</b></td>';
```

Comment: Remove the `onclick=` inside the parenthesis; it'll work with `onclick="copyToClipboard(\'test\')"`. The way it is right now, you call `copyToClickboard` only the first time; the next time you'll have its result (which is `undefined`) set as event handler.

Comment: wow, completely true I feel so bad about this, sometimes resting your eyes are so important on coding thanks so much raina77ow.